# SSD Bounding Box Rectangle Scaling

Tags: android, tensorflow, object-detection, multilabel-classification, tensorflow-lite

I have this screen on Android app, the blue area describes the Camera preview.
The app running SSD object detection classifier and returns bounding box/rect coordinates, I'm facing a problem scaling the coordinates and make the bounding box fit the Camera preview (blue area).

What calculations will make the bounding box correctly detect and draw the rectangle on the right place/coordinates?

The rectangle has:

- Width
- Height
- Left
- Top
- Right
- Bottom

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The SSD visualisation is here  https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/utils/visualization_utils.py

and from 
https://github.com/kcg2015/traffic_light_detection_classification/blob/master/tl_detection_classification_test.py

where dim is the dimension of the original image. scalefactor if you are drawing on the scaled image

```
def box_normal_to_pixel(box, dim,scalefactor=1):
    height, width = dim[0], dim[1]
    ymin = int(box[0]*height*scalefactor)
    xmin = int(box[1]*width*scalefactor)

    ymax = int(box[2]*height*scalefactor)
    xmax= int(box[3]*width*scalefactor)
    return np.array([xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax])
```

Comment: sorry do you know how to find predicted image ID from SSD? as I asked here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60398211/predicted-image-id-and-box-from-ssd